# R foreach loop, unable to rbind after added if statement

Tags: r, if-statement, parallel-foreach

i'm trying to rbind multiple dataframe using foreach loop with if else statement. Before adding if else statement, dataframe are able to rbind and running smoothly. But after added if else statement, the result table (M_test) become NULL, but the foreach loop run completely without any error.

```
system.time(
  M_test <- foreach(h = 1:50, .combine=rbind, .packages="data.table") %dopar% {

# Convert datafram to vector by row
v_items <- temp2[h,]

# Remove blank & NA
v_items <- v_items[v_items != "NA"]
v_items <- v_items[v_items != ""]

rules <- arules::apriori(trans,parameter=list(supp=0.001,conf=0.1, target = "rules", minlen=2),
               appearance=list(lhs=c(as.character(v_items)),default="rhs"))


if(length(rules)!=0){
rules_df <- arules::DATAFRAME(rules)

data.table(
  Key=T_test[h,1],
  LHS=rules_df$LHS,
  RHS=rules_df$RHS,
  support=rules_df$support,
  confidence=rules_df$confidence,
  lift=rules_df$lift,
  count=rules_df$count
)}
else{
rules_df <- data.frame(LHS=as.character("NA"),
                       RHS=as.character("NA"),
                       support=as.numeric(0),
                       confidence=as.numeric(0),
                       lift=as.numeric(0),
                       count=as.numeric(0))

data.table(
  Key=T_test[h,1],
  LHS=rules_df$LHS,
  RHS=rules_df$RHS,
  support=rules_df$support,
  confidence=rules_df$confidence,
  lift=rules_df$lift,
  count=rules_df$count
)
} 
}
)
```

Comment: What happens with a regular loop? Replace `M_test <- foreach(h = 1:50, .combine=rbind, .packages="data.table") %dopar% {` with `M_test <- lapply(1:50, function(h) {`

Comment: hi Parfait, i did try your suggestion using lapply, the result is the same :)

Comment: So `lapply` which is supposed to return a list returns just `NULL` and not some elements within list as `NULL`? With no error? I need to test this out. Can you post  sample data of *temp2*: `dput(head(temp2), 10)`?